# Did stash behavior change with git versions?

Tags: git

I did a `git stash` and later a `git stash apply` after pulling in the latest changes from the remote. This led to conflicts which I wanted to resolve using `git mergetool`, but unfortunately tkdiff opened with which I'm not familiar. So I wanted to retry merging using kdiff3 (which I *am* familiar with) but git said no files need merging (so it seems tkdiff changed the state to merged despite the file still containing merge markers).
So I thought, scrap it, I'll use the reflog to go back to a previous state. But then for some reason, the stashed work did not show up in the `stash list` when I inspected it, `stash@{0}` showed some much older stash I had done earlier.

So my question is: did I drop my stash when I used the reflog (`git reset --hard <reflog_id>` or did `stash apply` behavior change somehow with git versions (the one I was using on that specific machine is ancient 1.7.1)?

P.S.: I know I should have been more carful and should have committed my changes to some temporary branch.

Comment: The `git stash` code *has* changed over time, but not in any way that should do anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately any question of the form "here is a prose description of what I did and what happened, from memory; please explain it" is not fully answerable.  The best I think we can do is rule a few things out.

Unless you somehow checked the stash ref out as a branch, the `reset` command will not have changed the stash stack.  (Since you didn't specify *what* reflog entry you reset to, I ran a few tests that seemed like potential edge cases; I couldn't induce this type of failure even by resetting to the stash itself.)  And when I say "Unless you somehow checked the stash ref out as a branch"... this is possible by direct manipulation of the `HEAD` file, but the result would be to add a corrupt stash to the list, not to remove the current top stash.

I'm not aware of any change in the behavior of stash.  Whether or not the stash is dropped from the stack is the difference between `stash apply` and `stash pop`, and has been for as long as I've known about `git stash`. My historical knowledge is certainly not the most extensive around here, so maybe someone else knows something I don't, but the oldest docs I could find still draw this same distinction between pop and apply.